# How to apply currying to a existing normal function in scala

Tags: scala

I have the below function in scala

Now i would like to apply currying to this function

```
scala> def add(x:Int,y:Int) = x+y
add: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> val addCurried = Function.curried(add_)
 <console>:7: error: value curried is not a member of object Function
   val addCurried = Function.curried(add_)
                             ^

 scala> val addCurried = Function.curried(add _)
 <console>:8: error: value curried is not a member of object Function
   val addCurried = Function.curried(add _)
```

What went wrong here? How do i apply currying to an exixting function in scala

Answer (score 1):

```
val addCurried = (add _).curried
```

As you can see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Function$), there is no `curried` method on the `Function` object.